# Getting selected row off DataGrid when selecting a ContextMenu MenuItem on that row? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to get the selected row values when a row is right clicked and a contextmenu menuitem is selected. I am using DataTables to fill my datagrid. Here is how I fill the table:

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id as ID, name as Group_Name,   order_ascend as Display_Order FROM groups", MyConString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(ds);
dg_unassigned.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Here is my code in trying to retrieve it:

```
Group group = (Group)dg_unassigned.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(group.Name);
```

This is the error I get:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the selected row as a Group because you didn't set the itemsSource as a collection of Group (a List< Group> for example).

So in your case the .SelectedItem gives a DataRowView, you shoud write

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dg_unassigned.SelectedItem;
```

Then you can get a Group object this way:

```
Group group = new Group { Name = drv["Name"].ToString() };
```

I don't know how your table looks like, but you can access any field in your table with

```
drv["nameOfTheField"].ToString();
```

After that this code should work!

```
MessageBox.Show(group.Name);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked! I have another issue now, I am using CellEditEnding for update, but when I change the value in the cell, drv["fieldName"] returns the old value. How would I get this new value so I can use to update my database? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, I used string newValue = (e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text; Thanks again!! I would upvote if I could :(

Comment: I was going to answer but you find by yourself that's even better! If the answer solved your problem you can mark as accepted :)